# Wordpress, Using a themes options page in admin, if checkbox checked add html to header.php

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am making my first theme options/settings page for my theme.

I'm adding a part for my slider but in some cases I won't want the slider there so I'm going to add a checkbox so if it has been checked, it will add a div tag to my header page, if it's not checked then nothing will appear.

I thought about using a short code but this will stay in place and show the short code name if not selected.

Here's my checkbox form in php

```
<?php
function hero_options_page() {
  if ( $_POST['update_hero_options'] == 'true' ) { hero_options_update(); }
?>
<div class="wrap">
  <form method="post" action="<?php admin_url( 'themes.php?page=theme-settings' ); ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="update_hero_options" value="true" />
    <?php
      <input type="checkbox" name="display_hero" id="display_hero" <?php echo get_option('theme_display_hero'); ?> />
    ?>
    <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON-->
    <p class="submit" style="clear: both;">
      <input type="submit" name="Submit"  class="button-primary" value="Update Options" />
    </p>
    <!-- /SUBMIT BUTTON-->
  </form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here's how I get the results and save if it's checked or not

```
function hero_options_update() {
if ($_POST['display_hero']=='on') { $display = 'checked'; } else { $display = ''; }
update_option('theme_display_hero',     $display);

//If checked add html to header.php

}
?>
```

UPDATE 11/01/2014 @ 15:45

I'm trying to use the following code as mentioned with a little added

```
$c = get_option('display_header');
if ('checked' == $c) {
    function add_header_function() { 
    echo 'your content';
    }
}
add_shortcode('add_header', 'add_header_function');
```

Here's what i'm placing in the header, either will be fine i'f i could get it to work.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[add_header]'); ?>
<?php get_option('display_header'); ?>
```

Comment: Where is that code-- last two blocks? I am guessing it is too late for the hook you are trying to use.

Comment: You may be interested in having a look on my admin panel: github.com/maximski/Inferno it provides an easy syntax to create full featured and accessible admin options :) (and is pretty beautiful by the way)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839904/how-to-get-the-values-of-wordpress-customize-checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming/inferring/guessing that the question is "How do I make this work on the front-end?" So, use [`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).

```
$c = get_option('theme_display_hero');
if ('checked' == $c) {
  echo 'your content';
}
```

Your shortcode should probably be:

```
function add_header_function() { 
    $c = get_option('display_header');
    if ('checked' == $c) {
        echo 'your content';
    }
}
add_shortcode('add_header', 'add_header_function');
```

It is however, important *where* you define that function and add the shortcode.

Comment: Updated the main code but i still can't get it to work.

Comment: Used your short code and now the headset.php doesn't show the short code which means it's doing something but it's doing something but not populating

Comment: @Dan: unless you post more detail, I can't help.