# How to get the values of Wordpress customize checkboxes

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, customization

I can't figure out how to get the value - whether they are checked or not - from checkboxes in the WP customize manager.

This is the code in functions.php:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('social_facebook', array(
    'type'       => 'option',
));

$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'social_facebook',
        array(
            'label'          => __( 'Facebook', 'theme_name' ),
            'section'        => 'social-icons',
            'settings'       => 'social_facebook',
            'type'           => 'checkbox',
        )
    )
);
```

And this is how I try to get the value:

```
<?php
$facebook = get_theme_mod('social_facebook');
if ($facebook != ''){?>
<style>
    .facebook {display:inline!important;}
</style>
<?php }
?>
```

They values of the checkboxes are either "" (empty) or "1", so the system registers the checking of them. However, I don't know how to get the value through the get_theme_mod approach. Also, they don't have any name values, so I can't get the value through the usual way either.

Comment: get_theme_mod() works with set_theme_mod() not Settings API

Comment: So, you suggest that I do what?

Comment: `get_theme_mod()` does work with the Settings API, but only if the setting type is `theme_mod` (or unspecified).  Here the setting type is specified as `option`, so `get_option()` is needed to retrieve its value.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242615/using-get-theme-mod-with-checkbox-to-display-content/411586

Answer (score 5):

```
$sticky_mod = get_theme_mod( 'wca_header_section_sticky' ) == '1' ? 'sticky' : '';
```

This is an example in my case - if that option is checked, it will echo a "sticky" class in my template.

Answer (score 3):

if the setting 'my_theme_settings[social_facebook]' checkbox is unchecked:

```
<?php if( get_theme_mod( 'my_theme_settings[social_facebook]' ) == '') { ?>

 //if setting is unchecked content here will be shown

<?php } // end if ?>
```

For full article see: http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-theme-customizer

Answer (score 2):

Try use and customize this (tested, in functions.php:

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ){
  $wp_customize->add_section(
  // ID
  'layout_section',
  // Arguments array
  array(
    'title' => __( 'Layout', 'my_theme' ),
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'description' => __( 'social needs ;)', 'my_theme' )
  )
 );

 $wp_customize->add_setting(
  // ID
  'my_theme_settings[social_facebook]',
  // Arguments array
  array('type' => 'option')
  );

 $wp_customize->add_control(
  // ID
  'layout_control',
array(
  'type' => 'checkbox',
  'label' => __( 'Facebook', 'my_theme' ),
  'section' => 'layout_section',
  // This last one must match setting ID from above
  'settings' => 'my_theme_settings[social_facebook]'
 )
 );
}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

to read in template

```
$my_theme_settings = get_option( 'my_theme_settings' );
echo $my_theme_settings['social_facebook'];
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in the WP_Customize_Setting::value() it expect to return false
to uncheck the checkbox (or leave the checkbox unchecked) while some program will return '0' or ''.

In my case I have to extend the WP_Customize_Setting and override the value() method to force returning boolean.

```
<?php
class ForceBooleanSettings
extends WP_Customize_Setting {

  public function value() {
    return (bool) parent::value();
  }
}

// Example on using this extend class
$customizer->add_setting(new ForceBooleanSettings(
   $customizer, 
   'myuniquekey', 
   array(
    'default' => false,
    'transport' => 'refresh',
)));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working solution:

```
function theme_name_custom_settings( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'social_facebook', array(
        'default'   => 1, // Set default value
        'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_attr', // Sanitize input
        )
    );

    $wp_customize->add_control( 
        new WP_Customize_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            'social_facebook', // Setting ID
            array(
                'label'     => __( 'Facebook', 'theme_name' ),
                'section'   => 'social_icons', // No hyphen
                'settings'  => 'social_facebook', // Setting ID
                'type'      => 'checkbox',
            )
        )
    );

}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'theme_name_custom_settings' );
```

Then check it's value (0 or 1) like so:

```
if ( !get_theme_mod( 'social_facebook' ) ) { // false
    return;
}

// or

if ( get_theme_mod( 'social_facebook' ) == 1 ) { // true
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="facebook" <?php echo ( get_theme_mod( 'social_facebook' ) ) ? "style='display:none;'" : "" ?>>
```

Comment: Please extend your answer with further information and explanations, so it is not just an unexplained block of code.