# How to check whether checkox is checked in wordpress customizer

Tags: wordpress

i am building a plugin and i want to add some settings which rely on checkboxes. if the user checks the checkbox how to know. i know how to get data from checkbox in php but got stuck in wordpress. Because we have no option to add name attribute to the checkbox. for example, i am adding a checkbox in customizer.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('ion', array(
        'sanitize_callback' => 'ion_checkbox'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize, 'ion', array(
        'label' => 'Check',
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'section' => 'search_submit_section',
        'settings' => 'ion'
    )));
```

As we see there is no option to add name attribute how we will know whether user has checked the checkbox or not. I hope you understand my question.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839904/how-to-get-the-values-of-wordpress-customize-checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

with `($wp_customize, 'ion', array....` the ID is `ion` you can get the value with

```
$ion_checkbox_checked = get_theme_mod('ion') ? true : false;
```

if the checkbox checked `get_theme_mod('ion')` will return `1` else `0`

Comment: will you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from our free [HoverCraft](https://github.com/littlebizzy/hovercraft/blob/master/footer.php) theme with inspiration from @ewwink:

```
<?php 
$hovercraft_scroll_to_top_checked = get_theme_mod( 'hovercraft_scroll_to_top' ) ? true : false;
if ( $hovercraft_scroll_to_top_checked == true ) { ?>
        <div class="scrollup-wrapper">
            <a class="scrollup-link" href="#top"><i class="material-icons arrow_upward">arrow_upward</i></a>
        </div><!-- scrollup-wrapper -->
<?php } ?>
```

There are lots of bad examples floating around re: checkboxes. Be sure you are sanitizing them as booleans same as the Twenty Twenty theme:

https://wp-a2z.org/oik_api/twentytwenty_customizesanitize_checkbox/

```
function sanitize_checkbox( $checked ) {
    return ( ( isset( $checked ) && true === $checked ) ? true : false );
}
```